# setOnFocusChangeListener for edittext inside Fragment(non-activity) class not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am new to android. I am trying to change the border of the edittext on focus.
Edittext is present inside a non-activity class. I have used drawable resource and setOnFocusChange method to set the border. But its not working.

This is my code.
ViewMap.java

```
public class ViewMap extends Fragment {

Context mContext;
public ViewMap(Context mContext)
{
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

MapView mapView;
GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
         ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_map, container, false);
     EditText txt = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.search);
        txt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.focus_border_style);
                }
                else
                {
                    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lost_focus_border_style);
                }
            }
        });
 }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    }
    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    }
 }
```

view_map.xml

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/search"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:hint="Search location"/>

 <Button android:id="@+id/searchButton"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="Search"/>
```

Comment: Log the value in both if and else part and check what is happenning

Comment: Can you log to make sure both if and else are working?

Comment: i tried (!hasFocus) and (hasFocus == true) both.. it didnt work

Comment: Can you post both of your `drawables` (`focus_border_style` and `lost_focus_border_style`)?

Comment: focus_border_style.xml                                                                                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle" >
 <!-- border width and color -->
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#800000"
        />
    <!-- corner -->
 <corners android:radius="10dp"
     />
 
 <!-- padding -->
 <padding 
     android:bottom="5dp"
     android:left="10dp"
     android:right="5dp"
     android:top="5dp"
     />
</shape>

Comment: lost_focus_border_style                                                                                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    
    <!-- border width and color -->
    <stroke android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000"
        />
    <!-- corner -->
 <corners android:radius="10dp"
     />
 
 <!-- padding -->
 <padding 
     android:bottom="5dp"
     android:left="10dp"
     android:right="5dp"
     android:top="5dp"
     />

</shape>

Comment: @DEEPAKJAWALKAR did you try to log the value of hasfocus and check

Comment: i tried that as well